# Touchegg handles 3 and 4 finger events well, but 'ignores' 2 finger events

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, touchpad

I have installed Mint linux 16 with cinnamon, and I have an ASUS N550JV CN270H including a *multitouchpad* I tried different things to tweak multitouch gestures, namely:

Using support in xorg.conf as suggested here: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1361

I also used **ginn**, but it did not satisfy my needs; that is, I could not get it working. So I removed the xorg.conf file again, and purged ginn. Afterwards I tried **easystroke**, but I was not able to configure gestures which did not involve modifiers or clicks; maybe that is just me. So I removed it and now I use **touchegg**.

Touchegg is exactly what I am looking for, and it can detect up to 4 fingers (maybe even more, I did not test). However, it does not catch the 2 finger events. I simply compiled the touchegg source and ran the file in a console, which almost works fine. I guess the 2 finger events are caught by gnome (or cinnamon) and not passed trough (i.e. propagation is stopped). I think so is because gnome-control-center has the option to detect two finger gestures for simply scrolling:

[image: multitouch in gnome-control-center]

I disabled scrolling here, to allow gnome to pass these events without race condition consequences. Unfortunately that does not seem to work.

I am able to use two finger scrolling via the gnome-control-center interface and configure the rest via touchegg, however I would prefer handling all gestures via touchegg, in order to have a bit more functionality. Would this be possible? Can I get touchegg to receive all touch event? Is there a way to see what the 'event propagation stack' of these touch events is?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try configuring synaptics? Set the values you want to use to 0 and that should enable touchegg to control them. For instance,

```
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
```

`synclient` alone echoes a list of available parameters.

[source](https://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

Near the bottom of this post:
https://wdullaer.com/blog/2015/10/08/multitouch-trackpad-gestures-with-touchegg/

The author gives a list of synaptics configuration settings that should disable all two finger gestures. This might work for your scenario.